# error exception in .Net CF 3.5 framework using windows ce and vs 2008

Tags: c#, exception, embedded, .net-3.5, windows-ce

I'm working with windows CE on VS 2008 coding with C# on a windows form application. When I try to send my parameters to the electronic device through my serial connection suddenly it appears a strange popup on my windows CE device with:

> exception code: 0x80000002 address code: 0x40caff30 module that causes
>   the error: mscoree3_5.dll offset: 0x0004ff30
>   in ArrayList.GetEnumerator() in Application2.RunMessageLoop(Boolean
>   showform) in Application2.Run(Form mainForm, Boolean
>   runAsSingletonApp, Boolean displayMainForm) in Application2.Run(Form
>   mainForm) in Program.Main()

It appears randomly everytime i open a form or send data through my serial.

Comment: update: while debugging came out the same popup with the same exception code with exception address 0x40caf520 and offset: 0x0004f520.
in ModbusRtuTransport.Read(Int32 count)
in ModbusTrabsport.ReadResponse[T]()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The origin of the exception was due to the lack of size in my array of the buffer managed by the firmware. I solved it by simply expand the buffer's size in my firmware.